# How to use inheritance with ModelMapper's PropertyMap

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, modelmapper

I have been using the `ModelMapper` to convert `Identity` objects (entities) with `DTO` objects. I want to implement generic property conversions in a generic class for all entities (`GenericEToDtoPropertyMap`) and explicit property conversions in separate child-classes for each entity (`PersonEToDTOPropertyMap` for entity `Person`). To make it more clear, this is my code:

Generic property map:

```
public class GenericEToDtoPropertyMap<E extends Identity, DTO extends PersistentObjectDTO> extends PropertyMap<E, DTO> {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    // E.oid to DTO.id conversion
    map().setId(source.getOid());
  }

}
```

Specific property map for entity Person:

```
public class PersonEToDTOPropertyMap extends GenericEToDtoPropertyMap<Person, PersonDTO> {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    super.configure();
    // implement explicit conversions here
  }

}
```

Usage of property map:

```
modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
Configuration configuration = modelMapper.getConfiguration();
configuration.setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
modelMapper.addMappings(new PersonEToDTOPropertyMap());
// convert person object
PersonDTO personDto = modelMapper.map(person);
```

The problem is that the generic conversions do not apply. In my case `person.oid` does not get copied to `personDto.id`. It works correctly only if I remove the part:

```
map().setId(source.getOid());
```

from the `GenericEToDtoPropertyMap.configure()` method and put it in the `PersonEToDTOPropertyMap.configure()` method.

I guess, it has something to do with `ModelMapper` using `Reflection` to implement the mappings, but it would be nice if I could use inheritance in my property maps. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found an answer from the creator of `ModelMapper`, **Jonathan Halterman**:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modelmapper/cvLTfqnHhqQ

> This sort of mapping inheritance is not currently possible.

So I guess I have to implement all conversions in the child-class

Answer (score 0):

Well after 5 years... I got a solution (I have same problem)

After view some post and search answers I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58946113/modelmapper-propertymap-with-list-of-objects-to-a-responsedto)  The problem happen because the method "configure()" restricts what you can do inside so I thinking in create an method outside for get the custom format, so this is my code:

```
public class UserMap extends PropertyMap<User,UserLoginDTO> {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        using(generateFullname()).
                map(source,destination.getFullName());
    }

    private Converter<User, String> generateFullname(){
        return    context -> {
            User user = context.getSource();
        return user.getName()+ " " + user.getFirstLastname() + " " + user.getSecondLastname();
    };
    }

}
```

so you could call it from your main method or wherever you need, like this:

```
ModelMapper modelMapper=new ModelMapper();
modelMapper.addMappings(new UserMap());
```

and the output is:

```
 UserLoginDTO{id='001', fullName='Jhon Sunderland Rex'}
```

How you can see, the logic is out of configure method and it works, I hope this helps for others

pd: sorry for my english