# ModelMapper propertyMap with List of objects to a responseDTO

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

I'm new to modelMapper and I've encountered a problem when I tried to List of entity objects to a responseDTO.

User - Entity 
UserResponseDTO - response DTO

I did the following configurating for propertyMap.

```
        modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<List<User>, UserResponseDTO>() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                map().setName(source.get(0).getName());
                map().setEmail(source.get(0).getEmail());
                map().setUserRole(source.get(0).getUserRole());
                map().setLanguage(source.get(0).getLanguage());
                map().setTimeZone(source.get(0).getTimeZone());
                // ....have more mapping ahead
            }
        });
```

But it gives following errors:

> org.modelmapper.ConfigurationException: ModelMapper configuration errors:
>
> 1) Invalid source method java.util.List.get(). Ensure that method has zero parameters and does not return void.
>
> 2) Invalid source method java.util.List.get(). Ensure that method has zero parameters and does not return void.
>
> 3) Invalid source method java.util.List.get(). Ensure that method has zero parameters and does not return void.
>
> 4) Invalid source method java.util.List.get(). Ensure that method has zero parameters and does not return void.
>
> 5) Invalid source method java.util.List.get(). Ensure that method has zero parameters and does not return void.

Can anyone tell me how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly as the error message says:

> Ensure that method has zero parameters

This is because (below excerpt from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44739738/6413377))

> You receive these errors because `PropertyMap` restricts what you can do inside `configure().`

I find it hard to understand what you actually are trying to map because it seems that you just want to flatten some list of `User`s to a DTO containing data from a just a single user, namely the first in the list (*if not empty!*). Maybe you are not doing what you should or maybe you do it on a wrong manner. At least it seems that you do not need any special mappings.

Assuming your `User` and `UserResponseDTO` would be like (**simplified!**) :

```
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
}
```

and

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserResponseDTO {
    private String name;
    private String email;
}
```

then mapping single user would be like:

```
new ModelMapper().map(users.get(0), UserResponseDTO.class);
```

and if you would like to map the who list, like:

```
new ModelMapper().map(users, UserListResponseDTO.class)
```

then your `UserListResponseDTO` would simply be something like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class UserListResponseDTO extends ArrayList<UserResponseDTO> {}
```

or if it happens that you need to return a list with just the first user:

```
new ModelMapper()..map(Arrays.asList(users.get(0)), UserListResponseDTO.class)
```